# Bash : how to squeeze these 2 if statements into one

Tags: bash, scripting

I am new to Bash and scripting and I want to figure out a way to combine these two statements into 1 . what this script does is checks if two files D1 and D2 are the same file and if not checks if their content is the same.

```
if [ ! $D1 -ef $D2 ]

 then
    echo not the same file
        if  cmp -s $D1 $D2  

           then
            echo same info
           else
                echo not same info
        fi

    else
            echo same file


fi
```

In addition to this, I am also confused when to use [] and when to skip them, manual says when its a conditional use [], but what does that mean ?

Thank you.

Comment: `if` uses the *exit status* of [`test-commands`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) to decide which branch to follow. `[` happens to be [a command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-test) whose arguments are [conditional expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of an `if` statement is (from [2.10 Shell Grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10)):

```
if_clause        : If compound_list Then compound_list else_part Fi
                 | If compound_list Then compound_list           Fi
```

Where `compound_list` eventually gets down to a command.

`! $D1 -ef $D2` is not a command.

`[` is a a command (also known as `test`). See the output from `type [` or `type test` as well as `which [` and `which test`.

So `[ ! $D1 -ef $D2 ]` is a valid command used in the `if` statement.

The return value of the `compound_list` is what `if` tests.

So when you are using something like `cmp` (or any other command) then there is no reason to use `[` and, in fact, using `[` is incorrect.

As the `compound_list` can be more than a single command to combine `[ ! $D1 -ef $D2 ]` and `cmp -s $D1 $D2` simply use `&&` as normal. (Need `!` on the `cmp` call too to invert that to get the "not same" test from both.)

```
if [ ! "$D1" -ef "$D2" ] && ! cmp -s "$D1" "$D2"; then
    echo 'Not same file or same contents'
fi
```