# How does: `if ls /etc/*release 1>/dev/null 2>&1` work? An explanation please

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

Could someone help me under stand the condition `ls /etc/*release 1>/dev/null 2>&1` that's contained in the code:

```
    if ls /etc/*release 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
       echo "<h2>System release info</h2>"
       echo "<pre>"
       for i in /etc/*release; do

           # Since we can't be sure of the
           # length of the file, only
           # display the first line.

           head -n 1 $i
       done
       uname -orp
       echo "</pre>"
    fi
```

I pretty much don't understand any of that line but specifically what I wanted to know was:

1. Why dose it not have to use the 'test' syntax i.e. `[ expression ]`?
2. The spacing in the condition also confuses, is `1>/dev/null` a variable in the `ls` statement?
3. what is `2>&1`?

I understand the purpose of this statement, which is; if there exists a file with release in it's name under the `/etc/` directory the statement will continue, I just don't understand how this achieves this.

Thanks for you help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017143/bash-how-to-squeeze-these-2-if-statements-into-one/28017335#28017335

Comment: Thanks, that helps for point 3. but the others I also don't understand

Comment: That first link is point 2 and 3 (they are both just redirection). The second is point 1.

Comment: You can see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections for point 2 and 3 if you prefer the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[` isn't a special character, it's a command (`/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[`, usually a link to `test`). That means

```
if [ ...
if test ...
```

are the same. For this to work, `test` ignores `]` as last argument if it's being called `[`.

`if` simply responds to the exit code of the command it invokes. An exit code of 0 means success or "true".

`1>/dev/null 2>&1` redirects stdout (`1`) to the device `/dev/null` and then stderr (`2`) to stdout which means the command can't display and output or errors on the terminal.

Since stdout isn't a normal file or device, you have to use `>&` for the redirection.

At first glance, one would think that `if [ -e /etc/*release ]` would be a better solution but `test -e` doesn't work with patterns.

Comment: Thanks! Can you refer to stdout and stderr with the numbers in any part of the shell script or does it only work in conditional statements?

Comment: In the case of  `ls /etc/*release 1>/dev/null 2>&1` are they simply testing `if 1`?

Comment: @jcbermu I believe your right. From Aarons explanation of redirection I understand this simply redirects the exit status of  `ls` to basically say `if [ stderr -eq 0 ]`, i.e. there is a listing in /etc/ with the phrase release in it.

Comment: @Chriso: stderr is not related to the exit code. Exit code is in `$?` after a command was executed. `if [ stderr -eq 0 ]` is always false: `stderr` is no variable name (missing `$`). And you can't compare a file descriptor with a number.

Answer (score 0):

The `test` programm just evaluate its arguments and return a code 0 or 1 to tell whether it was true or not.

But you can use any shell commands/function with a `if`. It will do the `then` part if the return code (`$?`) was 0.
So, here, we look if `ls` return 0 (a file matched), or not.

So, in the end, it's equivalent to write `if [ -e /etc/*release ] ; then`, which is more "shell-liked".

The last two statements `1>/dev/null` and `2>&1` are just here to avoid displaying the output of the `ls`

- `1>/dev/null` redirect stdout to `/dev/null`, so the standard out is not shown
- `2>&1` redirect stderr to stdout. Here, stdout is redirected to `/dev/null`, so everything is redirected to `/dev/null`